# Executing code at regularly timed intervals in Clojure

Tags: clojure, timing

What's the best way to make code run at regular intervals in Clojure ? I'm currently using java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService, but that's Java - is there a Clojure way of scheduling code to run at regular intervals, after a delay, cancellably ? All the Clojure code examples I've seen use Thread/sleep, which also seems too Java.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well worth looking at the source code for [Overtone](http://overtone.github.com/), in particular the [code for scheduling events at a particular time](https://github.com/overtone/at-at/blob/master/src/overtone/at_at.clj).

It's a music synthesis system so you have to hope they have the timing code right!!

Also they have helpfully separated the timing code out into a separate project ([overtone/at-at](https://github.com/overtone/at-at)) so that you can easily import it if you want. This provides a nice Clojure wrapper to the underlying Java libraries (i.e. [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) and friends). The syntax is like this:

```
;; run some-function every 500ms
(every 500 some-function)
```

You can also shedule events at specific times:

```
;; run some-other-function 10 seconds from now
(at (+ 10000 (now)) some-other-function)
```

Comment: Great minds think alike perhaps :-) If you have good additions then do contribute back to overtone/at-at, would be great if we could develop a single great timing library in Clojure!

Comment: hmm not quite...same function names but a different approach. mine depends on clj-time...at-at looks good - thanks!

Comment: although, it's not quite what i need, as I also need things to be done at specific times on certain days

Comment: Great answer, I was thinking about requiring something like this in one of my projects, will be sure to check out `overtone/at-at`!

Comment: `overtone/at-at` seems to have been slightly neglected in the last months, this fork might be interesting: https://github.com/silasdavis/at-at

Answer (score 20):

From the clojure website http://clojure.org/concurrent_programming:

> In all cases, Clojure does not replace the Java thread system, rather it works with it. Clojure functions are java.util.concurrent.Callable, therefore they work with the Executor framework etc.

It sounds like you are already doing it the right way.

```
(import 'java.util.concurrent.Executors)
(import 'java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) 
(.scheduleAtFixedRate (Executors/newScheduledThreadPool 1) 
  #(println "Hello") 0 5 TimeUnit/SECONDS)
```

Comment: ok, but it feels silly to be dropping into Java to do something so ordinary!

Comment: One of the Clojure principals is to embrace the host platform (where it is powerful enough). In this case the clojure answer would be unlikely to go less than one expression.

Comment: interop is great, and certainly using Java makes sense for this, but I'd at least expect a wrapper for aesthetic reasons

Comment: IMHO here Java is not powerful enough: `ScheduledExecutorService` has 3 (4) methods and only one of them is overloaded to accept `Callable` instead of `Runnable`, with the unexpected outcome that exceptions in your scheduled function will be silently swallowed (without even printing anything to stderr!)... Obviously I don't really care about the result of a repeated scheduled function, so I don't really need a whole `Callable`... I had a look at `at-at` and unfortunately it seems that it doesn't wrap its fn argument in a try-catch-printstacktrace either

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question @ [Implementing a cron type scheduler in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234546/implementing-a-cron-type-scheduler-in-clojure?lq=1)

maybe [cronj](https://github.com/zcaudate/cronj) might help?

Answer (score 0):

The "tools.timer" library is a Java Timer wrapper: https://github.com/Ruiyun/tools.timer

It is very easy to use:

```
(use 'ruiyun.tools.timer)
(run-task! #(println "Say hello every 5 seconds.") :period 5000)
```