# How can I stop a repeating function gracefully in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a program that plays a little snippet of music. I want it to play in a loop for a while, but I want to be able to stop it gracefully, maybe with a keypress.

(BTW I tried to avoid saying "loop" or "keypress", because I didn't want to steer the answers in that direction.)

I'm still very much a beginner with clojure, and I'm currently just running from the REPL.

- Is it time for me to graduate to a better way to run my music function?
- How can I tell my function to stop gracefully when I want?

Comment: I believe you would play your music in a [future](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/future), that way you can [future-cancel](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/future-cancel) to stop gracefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually depends on your actual use case: Do you want to *kill* the music (i.e. interrupt it while playing) or do you just want to prevent it from playing the next time?

The latter case is easily dealt with using a promise that can be filled once you think silence should fall:

```
(defn play-music! []
  (let [p (promise)]
    (future 
      (while (= (deref p 0 ::timeout) ::timeout)
        ...))
    #(deliver p ::stop)))
```

This returns a function that can be called (without arguments) to stop the loop, e.g.:

```
(let [stop-fn (play-music!)]
  ;; ... do important music stuff ...
  (stop-fn))
```

This will stop the loop after the snippet has stopped playing. If you want to really interrupt it, you can use `future-cancel` (but the actual result of this depends on whether your piece of music is actually interruptible):

```
(defn play-music! []
  (let [fut (future
              (while true
                ...))]
    #(future-cancel fut)))
```

This also returns the stop function. There's a variety of ways to repeatedly perform an operation, most of it are detailed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21404130/1916789), including how to stop the resulting loop.

Comment: Good! I'd prefer to let the current "loop" finish, so I'll give stop-fn a try!

Answer (score 1):

xsc's answer is sophisticated, informative, and probably better, but it's worth mentioning a very, very simple answer that will probably work: Run it in Leiningen, and stop the function with Ctrl-C, which I consider fairly graceful--though not perfectly graceful.