# caching parsed data in clojure

Tags: parsing, caching, clojure

Say I do some parsing to generate a dataset. The job can be pretty slow, so is the loading of my webpage that is displaying the dataset.

Is there a way to tell the server to parse say every minute, to cache this and to rely on the cache to display results.

I've taken a look at [core.cache](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache) and its [docs](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache/wiki) but I can't figure out a simple way to just do that:

```
(require '[clojure.core.cache :as cache])

(def Dataset 
  (atom 
    (-> (parse-fn "http://nytimes.com")
        (cache/ttl-cache-factory :ttl 20000)))
```

How can the cache be refreshed do I can rely on it?

```
(build-html-table @Dataset)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start up an extra thread that handles the data updates (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21404130/1916789) for ways to periodically run a function), e.g.:

```
(defonce data (atom nil))
(defonce updater
  (future
    (while true
      (reset! data (parse-fn "http://nytimes.com"))
      (Thread/sleep 60000))))
```

To access the data:

```
@data
```

To cancel the updater:

```
(future-cancel updater)
```

Make sure to handle exceptions within `parse-fn`. Also, you might want to wait for the initial data to be available which could be achieved using a `promise` that gets `deliver`ed from within `updater`.

---

`core.cache` won't really work for your case unless you can accept that requests coming in after the TTL has expired will have to wait until the data is back in the cache. Also, when caching function results [`core.memoize`](https://github.com/clojure/core.memoize) already does most of the work for you:

```
(require '[clojure.core.memoize :as memo])
(defn fetch-dataset!
  (memo/ttl
    #(parse-fn "http://nytimes.com")
    :ttl/threshold 60000))

(fetch-dataset!) ;; => <your data> (takes a while)
(fetch-dataset!) ;; => <your data> (immediately)
... 60s ...
(fetch-dataset!) ;; => <your data> (takes a while)
```